# Register mocked objects in UnityContainer for Unit tests using Prism 7.1,x

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container, prism

I am migrating WPF application from Prism.Unity 6 to Prism.Unity 7. With Prism.Unity 7.1.0, I'm not able to create UnityContainer object directly. I want to create mocked/ stubbed objects and register it in UnityContainer, so that I can write unit tests.

```cs
private static readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
```

and then register the mocked object like this.

```cs
_unityContainer.RegisterInstance(_loggerStub.Object);
```

Both above statements are not compiling with Prism.Unity 7.1.0.x

Can anyone help me with the new Prism.Unity package for wpf for registering mocked objects in container. Any good documentation links available on the usage?

Comment: Do you have `using Unity;` somewhere at the start of your code?

Comment: Yes. I had it, but unit test classes were not recognizing the namespace. I just cross checked and found that, though I had installed Prism.Unity 7.1.0 in the unit test project, for some reason the dependent packages Unity.Container and Unity.Abstarctions were missing from references. I reinstalled and it is working fine now. Thanks for bringing to notice.

Comment: Why did you select mm8's answer as solution? If someone comes along later with the same problem, he's going to wonder how that will help him...

Comment: Seems I didn't note it being marked as answer. I have deselected it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `RegisterTypes` method in your `App.xaml.cs` class that inherits from `PrismApplication` in Prism 7:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(new YourSingletonObject())
}
```

Comment: I am trying to register mocked objects in UnityContainer as part of the unit tests. I could do it with earlier version of Prism.Unity 6.x. I am facing the issue when I am migrating the packages to Prism 7.1.x